# How can i install Ubuntu on my laptop without USB stick or DVD?

Tags: usb, live-usb, system-installation, dvd

How can I install Ubuntu on my laptop without USB stick or DVD?

I've a Dell Inspiron n5100 with Intel core i5 processor and now Windows 7 is installed in it. I want to keep both of these operating system if possible. And if not, I would like to keep Ubuntu but I don't have a USB stick or CD-ROM.

Is it possible without these? If yes, please help me throughout it, i'll be very thankful to you.

---

What is WUBI INSTALLATION. And how can i do it? .can anyone tell me step by step about it please..

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you cannot boot your computer on a usb stick or a dvd, the other way is to put your hard disk into another computer and install it, then put back your hard disk into your laptop.

This page contains the ways you can use to install Ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways you may wish to try is an "along side" wubi installation or a virtual machine running inside windows. Both of which you can download direct with any high speed internet connection and use right away.

Comment: Would be better if you could explain both the methods in detail.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've been trying lately is using [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), which allows you to create a bootable entry for ISOs directly. [Details here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/portable-entries/iso-images/). The program is free (for noncommercial use) and easy to use, so it's pretty painless.

I considered using [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer), but it does not support UEFI and as far as I know it will not be supported in releases of Ubuntu above 12.

Another possibility that is a bit more complicated would be to use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) with a [virtual hard drive mapped to the appropriate partition](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk), then mount the .iso as a drive in VirtualBox. I haven't tried that, though, but I see no reason to believe it wouldn't work.